# Regular expression to parse pipe delimited list of colon-delimited key-value pairs in tag body

Tags: regex

I want to scrape data from HTML.

The data I want is "Health Niche blogs".  What regex to write?

> fo width="80%" noWrap>**Author:** Health Niche Blogs | **Published:** Se

Comment: You should also mention which regex engine you're using (e.g., .net, perl, javascript, etc.), because they all have little syntax quirks.

Comment: You should also mention your language of choice because in Python -- for example -- we rarely use regex for this and instead use an add-on library.

Comment: You're much better off using a DOM parser when working with HTML. Regexes are ill-suited to that task.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have more specific requirements:

```
/Author\:\s+(.*?)\s+\|/
```